# Break down product lines UpTime/DownTime into Quarterly totals SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, sum, timestamp

I have a table, we will call tableA. Table A has the following columns:

```
 TableA
|  Date  |  Line   |  UpTime  | DownTime  |
```

For each date there is a product line with corresponding uptime and downtime. I need to break this data down to include a total for each product and then an analysis of each quarter. The following table would be an example of the final table.

```
|  Line  |  UpTime  |  DownTime  |  TotalTime  |  UpTime%  |
| Prod. A|  5000    |   3000     |    8000     |  62.5%    |
|   Q1   |  2500    |   1500     |    4000     |  62.5%    |
|   Q2   |  2500    |   1500     |    4000     |  62.5%    |
| Prod B |  5700    |   1200     |    6900     |  82.6%    |
|   Q1   |  3000    |   400      |    3400     |  88.2%    |
|   Q2   |  2700    |   800      |    3500     |  77.1%    |
etc. etc. for each product
```

As seen above, where you see a line with "Prod A" or "Prod B" the Uptime, DownTime, and TotalTime are all sums of quarter 1 and quarter 2. Underneath each "Prod X" line the times are broken into quarters. I have a query to return the totals for each product but do not know how to further break it down into quarters. If quarters 3 and 4 also show up this would not be a bad thing. Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT 
Line,
sum(UpTime) as 'UpTime',
sum(Downtime) as 'DownTime',
sum(uptime + downtime) as 'TotalTime'
FROM TableA
group by Line
order by line
```

This code returns all of the product totals. What do I need to add to further break this down into quarters?

Comment: "Underneath each "Prod X" line the times are broken into quarters. "  There is no "underneath".  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you don't have a column that specifies the ordering, or a column with the product on each row, then you cannot do what you want.  You mention a "date" column, but I don't see one.

Comment: You don't have enough data to do what you want. Unless each quarter is linked to a product, then that query will aggregate them all into one quarter. Looks like your design is flawed, in my opinion.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I do have a date column with the Line on each row. Could I use "Union All" do to this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried WITH ROLLUP?

```
SELECT Line,
       DATEPART(QUARTER, [Date]),
       sum(UpTime) as 'UpTime',
       sum(Downtime) as 'DownTime',
       sum(uptime + downtime) as 'TotalTime'
FROM TableA
GROUP BY Line, 
         DATEPART(QUARTER, [Date]) WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY Line
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` your existing query with a query that is GROUPed by both `Line`, and `DATEPART(QUARTER, [Date])`.

psuedocode:

```
{Your query that gets total sum}
UNION ALL
{Same query grouped by quarter as well as line}
ORDER BY {The order you want the rows in}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am not following you. Are you saying Union All or nest the select statement and cast the quarters?

Comment: I'm saying UNION ALL.

Comment: This does work, I am trying to rewrite it to show which quarter is showing.